# trigger.IO ajax -> trying to attach file to a Parse model

Tags: javascript, rest, trigger.io

I'm trying to attach an image file to a model in Parse using REST API and triggerIO; however am unsuccessful.

I am getting the error:

```
'{"type":"EXPECTED_FAILURE","content":"{\\"code\\":107,\\"error\\":\\"This endpoint only supports Content-Type: application/json requests, not application/x-www-form-urlencoded.\\"}","statusCode":"400","message":"HTTP error code received from server: 400"} [71.87s]'
```

this is the relevant code block:

```
attachImg: (data) ->
    uploadData =
        "picture": {
            "name": data,
            "__type": "File"
        }
    forge.request.ajax
        type: "POST", 
        url: "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/WorkoutLog",
        data: uploadData,
        dataType: "json"
        headers: 
            "X-Parse-Application-Id": 'MY-APP-ID',
            "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": 'MY-REST-API-KEY',
            "Content-Type": 'application/json'
        success: (data) ->
            debug "File attached"
        error: (err) ->
            debug err
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uploading image to Parse using Javascript(CoffeeScript) and REST API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16524967/uploading-image-to-parse-using-javascriptcoffeescript-and-rest-api)

Comment: This is to attach that file to a model (not upload file) but I've decided on a different method on attaching file to model - simply using the URL string. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided on using a different method for attaching files to models in parse by simply associating the file's URL string once uploaded to a column on the class.